# Portable AC or Dehumidifier?

Tags: home, air-conditioning

I currently am a recent graduate and I am living in a place that does not have AC. I am looking to buy a portable AC or to buy a dehumidifier. I currently live in Minnesota and sleeping at night when its 75+°F (24+°C) in the room is not my style.

Is it better to invest in a dehumidifier or a portable AC at this point? If the Portable AC I need one that is going to be able to fit through a 17 x 64 inch (43 x 162 cm) window... Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered a box fan in the window? If you set this to exhaust it removes warm inside air and draws in cool outside air. A dehumidifier will remove moisture but also add heat (from the compressor running).

Comment: A dehumidifier is not going to cool the room.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are open to other ideas, a fan with a cooling system behind it can be a cheaper and effective option.

Something like following image (source google) can be made with little investment.

[image]

There are simple version of the same.

[image]

All images sourced from google.